# Laravel9 usinglaravel-breeze with react, adding a new jsx not working at all

Tags: reactjs, laravel-9, laravel-breeze

I am trying to use Laravel9 with Reactjs using laravel-breeze.
I made a new jsx file named `Testpage.jsx` only to check it work but Laravel keep gives me 404 not found page.

This is the link part in a `Welcome.jsx` page.

```
<div className="ml-4 text-lg leading-7 font-semibold">
   <a href="/testpage"
      className="underline text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
   >
   Test
   </a>
</div>
```

And the `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/testpage', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Testpage');
});
```

And the `Testpage.jsx` which is exists in `resource/js/Pages/`, same as the `Welcome.jsx`.

```
import React from "react";

export default function Testpage() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>TEST!!!!</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

In the terminal, I am running the `npm run dev` command.
There are no errors at all.

I can see the 'Test' word in my Laravel page. However if I click the 'Test', then it shows me '404 | NOT FOUND' page.
And I checked the network tap in the browser, there is no `Testpage.jsx` at all.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

I was so stupid. It was not working because there was the route cache.